# Plus value in SUM Price

Tags: mysql

I have three tables in my database

Account, Users and Referral

If users referral id found in Accounts table, select the price and calculate the 20% of the price to the users who reffered that part is working fine, but if I add one more condition that
 if person referred person register himself then add price 10 to user who referred him in 'pris'. I have added one column in users table 'ten' for this, that if 
ten is equal to 0 then it means that user in newly registered so add price 10 in referred user (in pris). I have written following query but its not working according to the coniditons that
I mentioned.

```
SELECT *,
       Sum(a.price) * 0.2   AS pris,
       Monthname(a.created) AS mon,
       b.id,
       b.ten
FROM   accounts a,
       users b
WHERE  a.user_id IN (SELECT referrals.user_id
                     FROM   referrals
                     WHERE  referrer_id = '31')
        OR b.id IN (SELECT referrals.user_id
                    FROM   referrals
                    WHERE  referrer_id = '31')
           AND b.ten = '0'
GROUP  BY mon
LIMIT  1
```

Comment: perhaps, you should put last two condition in brackets like condA OR (condB and b.ten =0).Might solved your issue.Please Make your question clear.and provide output also.

Comment: plz give the structure of all the three tables. your above query is wrong because you are trying to get `a.id` and `b.ten` but `group by mon`